# Prove that a finite abelian group contains an element of order $m$ if and only if $m$ divides $n_1$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I'm working on the following problem from Dummit & Foote, Chapter 5.2:

> Let $G$ be a finite abelian group of type $(n_1, n_2, ..., n_t)$. Prove that G
>   contains an element of order $m$ if and only if $m$ divides $n_1$.
>   Deduce that $G$ is of exponent $n_1$.

But, I thought of the following (possible) counterexample to the $\implies$ direction:

Consider $|G| = 60 = 2^2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5$.

So, there are two possible isomorphism types of $G$ corresponding to the following cyclic decompositions:

$$Z_2 \times Z_2 \times Z_3 \times Z_5 \hspace{5mm} \text{ and } \hspace{5mm} Z_4 \times Z_3 \times Z_5. $$

The only invariant factor decomposition of $G$ is given by $n_1 = 30, n_2 = 2$. So, if we consider an element $g \in G$ of order $4$, then $|g|$ does not divide $n_1$.

Granted, I'm restricting this argument to just one of the isomorphism types, but I would assume that the proposition should hold regardless of isomorphism type. Does my argument not hold (again, restricting to only one of the isomorphism types), or is the proposition given only meant to hold for $some$ isomorphism type?

Comment: I presume in D&F one needs $n_2\mid n_1$, $n_3\mid n_2$ etc. In your first group there is no element of order $4$. Your second group has type $(60)$.

Comment: Right. I forgot that the cyclic decomposition is $determined$ $by$ the invariant factor decomposition. Thanks.

Comment: Please add that the groups you are talking about are Abelian.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Please put your comment into an answer so this doesn't show as unanswered.